# Getting a json response into variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, request, google-geocoder

I am trying to use the google geocoder api to get the longitude and latitude of an address to use in a map-making app.

how do i get the data from a geocode request (for instance:

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true" is the example used on the api site) into a variable in my script so I can extract data from it?  or is it possible to extract data another way?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so first things first... you're looking at using JavaScript, not Java.

I'm going to steer you in a bit of a different direction. You won't need JSON.

I'm assuming you're using the google maps javascript api? If not you should be.

To utilize the google maps api you'll need to include this `<script>` tag in the `<head>` section of your web page:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Add a second `<script>` tag to the `<head>` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
   var geocoder;

   function Geocode(address){
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log("Latitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            console.log("Longitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
         }
         else {
            console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
         }
      });
   } 
</script>
```

The above Geocode() function accepts an address as a parameter. It then makes a Geocode request via the Geocoder Object from the Google Maps API and passes the response from the Geocoder object into the callback function (function(results,status){...}). For a full reference of what the 'results' parameter being passed into the callback function contains look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderResult)

Hope this helps.

Comment: in that example what would the object in the javascript be called?  sorry i'm very new to using javascript! thanks!!

Comment: @AltheFuzz: Are you using JAVA or JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: javascript, i think - i'm doing it in script tags alongside html - really sorry for the confusion there

Comment: i did try using jquery earlier, but couldn't get my head around it - that would be awesome thanks! i have version 1.5.2.min if that's any help :)

Comment: @AltheFuzz: I take that back, jQuery won't be necessary but you'll want to utilize the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: have been playing around with it a little and that is great!  i think when i tried using something similar to this earlier i forgot to include the api...thanks dude this has had me stuck all day!! :)